# How to fix HTML validation Warning: <a> proprietary attribute 'role' or 'aria-expanded'

Tags: html

I am validating my HTML website built on bootstrap and got following warning. My question is that how should i fix this issue. Note: i have fixed more than 67 warnings but unable to fix these warnings. One thing i have searched lot on google but not found any post to fix this issue. Lastly, i have only one option i.e to ask here. Please help me

> line 87 column 75 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-expanded'
>     line 99 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute 'role'
>     line 99 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-haspopup'
>     line 99 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-expanded'
>     line 111 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute 'role'
>     line 111 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-haspopup'
>     line 111 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-expanded'
>     line 123 column 89 - Warning:  proprietary attribute 'role'

**[image: Warning Screen Shot:]**

***Here is the New  code which only contains the nav section and below is the warning ***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  header-top-menu" id="top-navigation-menu">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
</button>                                     
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home<span class="caret">&nbsp;</span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-custom">
<li><a href="#" >Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages<span class="caret">&nbsp;</span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-custom">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<!--multi level menu -->
<li class="dropdown" >
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" > Portfolio <b class="caret">&nbsp; </b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level dropdown-menu-custom">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu ">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Grid Layout</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu1">
            <li><a href="#">2 Columns </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3 Columns</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4 Columns</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Mansonry Layout</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu1">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio Item Page</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<!--/multi level menu -->


<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>                                     
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->                                 
</nav>
```

======================================================================

## Here is the warning which i am receiving

> line 4 column 75 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-expanded'
>     line 16 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute 'role'
>     line 16 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-haspopup'
>     line 16 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-expanded'
>     line 28 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute 'role'
>     line 28 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-haspopup'
>     line 28 column 83 - Warning:  proprietary attribute
>      'aria-expanded'
>     line 40 column 89 - Warning:  proprietary attribute 'role'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What doctype are you using? HTML 4.01 or HTML5? I suspect it's HTML 4.01, so I suggest you use: `<DOCTYPE html>` instead

Comment: I am using <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Hmm, very strange. And which validator are you using?

Comment: I would also argue that you should be using a button and not an a for that dropdown toggle, as it is a button that you have created.

Comment: No, i have not created the button just using Twitter Bootsrap Nav bar. I am using Kingsquare HTML Validator chrome extension for validation! This extension is available a the Google chrome apps store. I have attached image copy of my code in my question you can see it title as (enter image description here).

Comment: Yes I see the image, this is why I asked. I am not a fan of Bootstrap as it recommends a lot of non-semantic code which is bad in my opinion. But I digress. Back to your original problem...can you paste the actual code in here rather than post an image?

Comment: Where should i add the code it reaches maximum allowed characters in the comment section?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, so the validator is wrong. The W3C Validator (https://validator.w3.org/) says it's fine.

Comment: Have you checked this code on validator.w3.org? Then it might be issue with the chrome validator which i am using.